# Proof for Kinetic gas equation

Tags: thermodynamics

How do you prove kinetic gas equation without considering a specific shape of container/vessel?I looked for it in many sites but couldn’t find any reasonable derivation or at least I couldn’t get it.Some way or other a specific shape is involved...like constant area of cross-section or a cube.please check the proof by tim_lou in here : https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-derive-the-kinetic-gas-equation.138300/

The proof involves considering a uniform area of cross-section ( A )by which $nAV_x dt$ was written...If I am misinterpreting it,please do guide me.

Comment: Keep in mind that the original, highly-detailed treatments of the late 19th century ran to tens of pages, much of it dense math. Most of the treatment you see online are simplified by design.

Comment: @dmckee oh that’s the case ha! Fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of the kinetic theory is that gas consists of molecules with no volume that have an overall kinetic energy proportional to temperature and that each collide elastically. The analogy in one dimension is a highway where the cars have no size, travel with an average speed proportional to the average octane rating of the gas overall, and bounce off things (each other or the side berms) with no damage and no loss of their energy (speed).

The next step is to have the cars (molecules) bounce off a road block somewhere and return back elastically. The rate at which the cars bounce off the road block is proportional to their speed. That rate is independent of where the road block is positioned along the highway.

Now take a container with gas molecules. The rate at which the molecules change momentum at a wall is independent of where the wall is positioned. So, for one set of molecules, put the wall at position $z$. For another, put it at $2z$. The change in momentum is the same. The PRESSURE produced by the molecules is the same.

Now, for the last step, make the regions where the molecules collide infinitesimally small. No problem, the molecules have no size. Now, determine the collisions that are occurring on a macroscopic wall by integrating around the infinitesimal small regions over all the container. Since the collision rate is independent of where the region is positioned in the container (i.e. the cars still have the same elastic "pressure change" regardless of where the roadblock sits), pressure is independent of the shape of the container.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of a molecule having a specific speed, $\vec{v}$, is given by
$$P(\vec{v})dv_x dv_y dv_z\propto \exp\bigg(-\frac{m|\vec{v}|^2}{2k_BT} \bigg)dv_x dy_x dz_x$$
Transforming into spherical coordinates and integrating
$$P(\vec{v})\propto\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\exp\bigg(-\frac{m|\vec{v}|^2}{2k_BT} \bigg)v^2\sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi\ dv$$
As we are only working with proportionality the integrals
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi = 4\pi = \mathrm{const.}$$
can be dropped.

The average of the squared speed can be calculated by integrating $v^2 P(v)$ and dividing by $P(v)$. This gives
$$\langle v^2\rangle = \bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}v^4\exp\bigg(-\frac{m|\vec{v}|^2}{2k_BT} \bigg)\ dv\bigg)\ \bigg/ \bigg(\int_{0}^{\infty}v^2\exp\bigg(-\frac{m|\vec{v}|^2}{2k_BT} \bigg)\ dv\bigg) = \frac{3k_BT}{m}$$
From this we can write
$$\frac{1}{3}m\langle v^2\rangle = k_BT$$
and from the ideal gas equation we have
$$PV=Nk_BT \implies PV=\frac{1}{3}Nm\langle v^2\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you..but I’m high school student....is it possible for me to understand that? I’ll try to if yes..

Comment: The main thing to understand from this is the calculation of the average of the squared speed.  It is important to know that if there is a continuous variable $x$ then the average of any function $f(x)$ is given by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)P(x) dx$. In this, the function is a function of $v$, and is given by $f(v)=v^2$. We then divide the 'sum' of all the squared speeds by $P(v)$ to get the average.

Comment: what’s P(x)? is this not the average of f(x) across x $$\frac {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f(x)dx)}{\int dx}$$

Comment: $P(x)$ is the probability density function of the continuous random variable $x$.